# Define order of plots when plotting multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have four plots that I would like to plot on the same figure using:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4)
```

By default grid.arrange will plot the first two on the top and the other two in the bottom.
Is there a way to plot all four plots next to each other for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the argument `nrow = 1` if you want all plots in one row

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, nrow = 1)
```

You can also use the argument `ncol = 1` if you want all plots in one column

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4, ncol = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

using cowplot can give same result. Cowplot has plot grid that allows to arrange the plots in order as your wish.

```
plot_grid(p,q,align=c('h','v'),ncol=,labels=)
```

Use align to arrange the plot vertically(v) or horizontally(h), and labels to individually label each plot.